# How to select multiple columns which are not next to each other?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a dataset which I am trying to select the first 10 columns from, and the last 27 columns from (from the 125th column onwards to the final 152nd column).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} { printf $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10; for(i=125; i<=NF; ++i) printf $i""FS; print ""}' Bigdata.txt > Smalldata.txt
```

With trying this code it gives me the first 12 columns (with their data) and all the headers for all 152 columns from my original big data file. How do I select both columns 1-10 and 125-152 to go into a new file? I am new to linux and any guidence would be appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly clear what is NOT working, please do mention more clearly what is not exactly working in your post and let us know then?

Comment: Dear DN1, first of all welcome to Stack Overflow. As you mentioned in your last couple of questions, you are new to Linux and Awk. In order to understand awk a bit better, I strongly recommand you to have a look at [Awk one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/) and the tag-info [tag:awk]

Comment: between 125 to 152 (inclusive) there are 28 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} 
     { c=""; for(i=1;i<=10;++i)     { printf c $i; c=OFS}
             for(i=NF-27;i<=NF;++i) { printf c $i       }
       printf ORS }' file
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is working for me, and thank you for the links you provided I will look into them now before going forward with my code.

Answer (score 2):

don't reinvent the wheel, if you already know the number of columns `cut` is the tool for this task.

```
$ cut -f1-10,125-152 bigdata
```

tab is the default delimiter.

If you don't know the number of columns, `awk` comes to the rescue!

```
$ cut -f1-10,$(awk '{print NF-27"-"NF; exit}' file) file
```

`awk` will print the end range by reading the first line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, since no samples produced so couldn't test it. You need NOT to manually write `1...10` field values you could use a loop for that too.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{for(i=1;i<=10;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,OFS)};for(i=(NF-27);i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}}' Input_file > output_file
```

Also you need NOT to worry about headers here, since we are simply printing the lines and no logic specifically applied for lines so no need to add any specific entry for 1st line or so.

***EDIT:*** 1 more point here seems you meant that different column values(in different ranges) should come in single line(for a single line from Input) if this is the case then my above code should handle it, since I am printing spaces as separator for their values and printing a new only when their last field's value is printed, by this each line from Input_file fields will be on same line(as Input_file's entry).

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation here.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                      ##Starting BEGIN section here, which will be executed before Input_file is getting read.
  FS=OFS="\t"                               ##Setting FS and OFS as TAB here.
}                                           ##Closing BEGIN section here for this awk code.
{                                           ##Starting a new BLOCK which will be executed when Input_file is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=10;i++){                       ##Running a for loop which will run 10 times from i=1 to i=10 value.
     printf("%s%s",$i,OFS)                  ##Printing value of specific field with OFS value.
  }                                         ##Closing for loop BLOCK here.
  for(i=(NF-27);i<=NF;i++){                 ##Starting a for loop which will run for 27 last fields only as per OP requirements.
     printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)        ##Printing field value and checking condition i==NF, if field is last field of line print new line else print space.
  }                                         ##Closing block for, for loop now.
}' Input_file > output_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here, whose output is going into output_file.
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Apologies as I am very new to linux so there's a lot I am not sure of. This code you have provided works, however columns 1-10 are being printed in only 1 column, which is then followed by the columns 125-152 each with their own seperate column as I am looking for

Comment: This does the same but puts % inbetween, so for example the first column is called: "Chr%2Start%2End%2Ref%2Alt%2Func.refGene%2Gene.refGene%2GeneDetail.refGene%2ExonicFunc.refGene%2AAChange.refGene%2id.snp2"

and is followed by the 27 other individual columns from the 125-152 selection